Emacs evil-yank changes clipboard
I use emacs. Until now evil-yank just copied contents to kill ring not
changing global clipboard. But suddenly it began to copy contents to clipboard.
What can be the cause of this problem?
I checked my evil-yank definition.
(evil-define-operator evil-yank (beg end type register yank-handler)
  "Save the characters in motion into the kill-ring."
  :move-point nil
  :repeat nil
  (interactive "<R><x><y>")
  (let ((evil-was-yanked-without-register
         (and evil-was-yanked-without-register (not register))))
    (cond
     ((and (fboundp 'cua--global-mark-active)
           (fboundp 'cua-copy-region-to-global-mark)
           (cua--global-mark-active))
      (cua-copy-region-to-global-mark beg end))
     ((eq type 'block)
      (evil-yank-rectangle beg end register yank-handler))
     ((memq type '(line screen-line))
      (evil-yank-lines beg end register yank-handler))
     (t
      (evil-yank-characters beg end register yank-handler)
      (goto-char beg)))))

M-x evil-yank and "y" hotkey acts the same way(changes the clipboard).
It is not supposed to change clipboard. What could be the cause of this behavior?

I didn't notice that this was a default behavior.
From emacs manual

When an Emacs kill command puts text in the clipboard, the existing clipboard contents are normally lost. Optionally, Emacs can save the existing clipboard contents to the kill ring, preventing you from losing the old clipboard data. If save-interprogram-paste-before-kill has been set to a number, then the data is copied over if it’s smaller (in characters) than this number. If this variable is any other non-nil value, the data is always copied over—at the risk of high memory consumption if that data turns out to be large.


Yank commands, such as C-y (yank), also use the clipboard. If another application “owns” the clipboard—i.e., if you cut or copied text there more recently than your last kill command in Emacs—then Emacs yanks from the clipboard instead of the kill ring.


Normally, rotating the kill ring with M-y (yank-pop) does not alter the clipboard. However, if you change yank-pop-change-selection to t, then M-y saves the new yank to the clipboard.


To prevent kill and yank commands from accessing the clipboard, change the variable select-enable-clipboard to nil.

